# Is there anyway can query in Hive to query some metrics and verify whether they satisfy some formulas after join two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I got two tables in Hive:

`a.hive`:

|rid|cid|a|b|c|

`a.samples`

|rid|cid|a|b|c|

The two tables have the same field names.Now I want to take out the parts with the same rid and cid of these two tables, and then verify whether the difference between the values in the three fields of a, b, and c is less than 0.00001 (output true/false in the query result), and output the percentage that the difference between the values is less than 0.00001 in these three fields. I currently wrote the code for the first part but it throws an error and I don't know how to output the percentage. How should I do?

```
select s.rid, 
       s.cid
from a.samples s
join a.hive h
if(s.a - h.a < 0.00001, 'True', 'False') as result_a,
if(s.b - h.b < 0.00001, 'True', 'False') as result_b,
if(s.c - h.c < 0.00001, 'True', 'False') as result_c
on (s.rid = h.rid and s.cid = h.cid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT s.rid
     , s.cid
     , IF(s.a - h.a < 0.00001, 'True', 'False') AS result_a
     , s.a / h.a - 1                            AS percentage_a
     , IF(s.b - h.b < 0.00001, 'True', 'False') AS result_b
     , s.b / h.b - 1                            AS percentage_b
     , IF(s.c - h.c < 0.00001, 'True', 'False') AS result_c
     , s.c / h.c - 1                            AS percentage_c
FROM a.samples    s
INNER JOIN a.hive h ON s.rid = h.rid AND s.cid = h.cid
```